# Query diff from previous matching row, with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

To diff a row with a previous row, I am `JOIN`ing a table to itself and comparing with the previous `id` (primary key):

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
    id INT(5) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data INT
);

SELECT t1.id, t1.data, t1.data-(SELECT data FROM tablename WHERE id=t1.id-1) AS diff
FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY diff DESC LIMIT 1;
```

How can I restrict this to only a particular subset of the data? For instance, if a column `user VARCHAR(32)` is added to the table, how might I restrict the query to only diff the particular user? Adding a simple WHERE clause to the two `SELECT` queries won't work as the whole premise depends on sequential `id`s. I suppose that I could move the data into a temporary table but if there is a cleaner, more efficient solution then I would use that.

My intention is to add a `WHERE user='someUser'` clause, for which the diff will diff only for a particular user, not the whole table.

Here is a working [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1bd79/1). I would like to modify this query so that it works only for `WHERE name='a'`, so that the result would be `id=9, data=305, diff=125`.

Comment: The id in the desired result would be 9. You have no 16 rows in your sqlfiddle. Just mentioning, so noone is confused. Not editing myself, cause I provided answer and noone shall say I cheated :)

Comment: Thanks tombom, you are correct and I made the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT id, data, data - COALESCE(previous, data) as diff FROM (
SELECT
t.*,
@prev AS previous,
@prev:=t.data 
FROM
tablename t
, (SELECT @prev:=NULL) var
where name = 'a'
)sq
order by diff desc
limit 1
```

Explanation:

```
, (SELECT @prev:=NULL) var
```

Initialization of variable.

```
@prev AS previous,
@prev:=t.data
```

Output the current value of the variable in first column, in second column assign the value of the current row.

```
COALESCE(previous, data)
```

If previous is `NULL`, return value of column data. Therefore the row which has no previous row has a diff of zero.

Feel free to ask if you have more questions.

P.S.: This query could even well be faster than ones where you have to self join.

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing. I did not know about `COALESCE` and I like your eloquent use of MySQL session variables.

Comment: This is a very informative answer with a very clever solution. Thank you tombom!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you should use something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.data data_curr, t2.data data_prev, t1.data - t2.data data_diff
FROM (
  SELECT t1.id, t1.data, MAX(t2.id) max_id
  FROM
    tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name
       AND t1.id > t2.id
  WHERE
    t1.name = 'a'
  GROUP BY
    t1.id, t1.data
) t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.max_id = t2.id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5df4/11). This is standard SQL and should work on any DBMS.

If however you just need the LAST diff of data, you could use `LIMIT 1` (ordering by ID DESC) on your main query to get the last data where name='a', and then `LIMIT 1,1` to get the second last data:

```
SELECT   id, data data_curr,
         data -
         (SELECT data FROM tablename WHERE name='a' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1) data_diff
FROM     tablename
WHERE    name='a'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Please see it [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7d83/1).

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, it seems the value of data field is rising and the difference shall always be a positive value

This should work

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  max(data)-min(data) as diff,
  max(data) as data
  name
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      data,
      name 
    FROM 
      tablename 
    WHERE 
      name = 'a' 
    ORDER BY
      id desc 
    LIMIT 2 
  ) t
GROUP BY 
  name
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6507c/4) demo

Comment: Thank you Akash. This seems to return the last diff, not the highest diff.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this - although tombom's version scales better...

```
 SELECT a.id
      , a.data
      , a.name
      , a.data-b.data ttl
   FROM
      ( SELECT x.* 
             , COUNT(*) rank 
          FROM tablename x 
          JOIN tablename y 
            ON y.name = x.name 
           AND y.id >=x.id 
         GROUP 
            BY x.id
      ) a
   JOIN
      ( SELECT x.* 
             , COUNT(*) rank 
          FROM tablename x 
          JOIN tablename y 
            ON y.name = x.name 
           AND y.id >=x.id 
         GROUP 
            BY x.id
      ) b
     ON b.name = a.name
    AND b.rank = a.rank + 1
  WHERE a.rank = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not a good practice but i sometimes join the semi join like this

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.data,
  t1.data- t3.data AS diff
FROM tablename t1
  LEFT JOIN tablename t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
  LEFT JOIN tablename t3
    ON t3.data = (SELECT
            data
          FROM tablename
          WHERE id > t1.id
          LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY diff DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Raheel Shan, but this does not let me restrict the query to only diffing for a particular user. I will make that part of the question clearer.